# jQuery event affecting only this instance of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have more than one element with the same class name, ideally they will be seven, so, on pageload they will be hidden and then I want to show the extra text when clicking on the anchor, but only for that very instance of the div, my jQuery code is currently removing hidden in all instances of the div, I am guessing the solution would be to add `this` somewhere. Thanks!

```js
$(".show-more").click(function() {
  return $(".extra-text").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p class="hidden extra-text">More text</p>
  <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more..</a>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p class="hidden extra-text">More text</p>
  <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more..</a>
</div>
```

Comment: On a related note, you may be interested is using `slideToggle()` over `.toggleClass("hidden")` as it's less jarring and accomplishes the same result.

Comment: Good point, but it seems that the functionality brakes when I replace it, might have to look into it. thx

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ptbLg5uj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse the DOM to find the `.extra-text` element related to the one which raised the event.

To do this you can use the `this` keyword which will refer to the element that raised the click event. Try this:

```
$(".show-more").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find(".extra-text").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: get rid of the return, it is not needed

Answer (score 2):

Use `.prev()` in this context.

```
$(".show-more").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).prev().toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ndwwt4v/)

Answer (score 2):

`.extra-text` is sibling to `.show-more`, so u can use **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** method to get adjacent sibling element

```js
$(".show-more").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".extra-text").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p class="hidden extra-text">More text</p>
  <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more..</a>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p class="hidden extra-text">More text</p>
  <a href="#" class="show-more">Show more..</a>
</div>
```